# How to share assets (such as images) in an angular-artefact that never gets published?

Tags: angular, angular-library

In the same angular workspace next to my two applications I have a library-typed project, let's call it `core` and I use it to share code between my other two apps and I just import files from `core` in my projects via a normal import:
`import {BaseState} from '../../../some-core/src/lib/model/base-state.model';`
I don't intend to release this library as a separate library and everything seems to work, but I'm not able to share assets from the `core` between apps and `ng-packgr` is not in the business since I don't publish the library. Is there a way to share assets without using `ng-packagr`? Also is this a valid way to share code and use library in a no-publishing manner?

Comment: Did you try to deploy your apps in a test environment? I am not sure the code sharing will work this way. You better build another app that acts as a service and call it from your other apps via http requests. This would make your logics callable from any app you would like.

Comment: it definitely works.